# Spring Social Facebook: how to get post's owner which is liked by authenticated user

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I have developed a Spring application which uses Spring Social Facebook, in order to get users activities in social network.

I need to know how i can get post's owner which is liked by authenticated user, and which permission is required to perform this operation.

***For sake of clarity: User A (authenticated) likes a post belonging to user B. How i can get user B?***

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have url from facbook api explorator

```
me/posts?fields=from,message,picture,icon
```

This rest execution should return all posts - posted by current user and other users which was liked by him/her. Know you have to write it in Java, below code fetches data from the specified connection.

```
facebook.fetchConnections(null, "music", Page.class,
            new PagingParameters(25, 0, null, null).toMap(), "from,message,picture,icon")
```

You can also try (but this I haven't tested)

```
facebook.fetchConnections(null, "posts", Post.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried the url in api explorer but i get only my posts and not also friends' posts i liked